# Testing recursive class methods using unit testing python

Tags: python-3.x, unit-testing, class, recursion, pytest

```
class Login:


    def admin_login(self):
        user_name = input('Enter UserName: -')
        password = input('please enter password:- ')
        try:
            with open(r'/home/Downloads/amis/config.yaml') as file:
                credentials = yaml.load(file)
                if credentials['userid'] == user_name and credentials['password'] == password:
                     admin_op = AdminOps(credentials)
                     admin_op.admin_ops()
                else:
                     print("please enter correct login creds")
                     self.admin_login()

        except:
            print('err')
            self.admin_login()
```

*I am testing this class method and i am trying to mock the method then it is not even going into this method for testing. Can anyone help me writing unit test for this class method.*

I tried this for the wrong credentials.

```
@mock.patch('users.logins.input', create=True)
def test_admin_login_fail(self,ext, inp1):
    inp1.side_effect = ['qqq', 'qqq']
    login_cls = Login()
    login_cls.admin_login()
    with mock.patch('file path') as mock_login:
        assert mock_login.called
```

Answer (score 0):

**reproducible problem**

Admittedly I don't know much about `pytest` but the problems I see are generic ones and not linked to use of a specific language or library. I'm going to simplify the problem a little bit. Hopefully it can show us a path forward -

```py
def login(creds = {}):
  u = input("username:")
  p = input("password:")

  if u in creds and creds[u] == p:
    print(f"{u} logged in")
  else:
    print(f"invalid login. please retry...")
    login(creds)

login({"ripley": "password1"})
```

I run the program -

```
username:foo
password:bar
invalid login. please retry...
username:ripley
password:password1
ripley logged in
```

**how to test?**

Okay, it works but I still have a testing problem. When an invalid login is provided, `login` loops endlessly. However, this is not a testing problem, it's a problem with how we wrote our program. The program has a problem of mixing concerns. We already separated one concern by passing `credentials` as an argument to the `login` function. Already, if there's a `read` or `yaml.parse` error, we don't have to deal with those *inside* of `login`. But there's additional concern of `input` and `print` side effects...

```py
def login(creds = {}, u = "", p = ""):
  return u in creds and creds[u] == p

creds = {"ripley": "password1"}

print(login(creds, "foo", "bar")) # False
print(login(creds, "ripley", "password1")) # True
```

Now testing is basic `login` functionality is easy -

```py
def test_login(self):
  assert login({}, "foo", "bar") == False
  assert login({"foo": "bar"}, "foo", "bar") == True
```

`creds`, `user`, and `pass` are all arguments to the `login` function so we can verify our function's behavior without worrying about `read` or `yaml.parse`

---

**write functions with parameters**

Okay, but what if we want to test `login` in a looping procedure? Again, we apply what we learned above and write functions that accept arguments -

```py
class ui:
  def __init__(self, creds, I, O): # <-- params: creds, input, output
    self.creds = creds
    self.I = I
    self.O = O
    self.user = None

  def login(self, exit = None): # <-- param: exit handler
    u = self.I("user:")
    p = self.I("pass:")
    if (login(self.creds, u, p)):
      self.O(f"{u} logged in")
      self.user = u
    elif exit is None:
      self.O("invalid login")
      self.login()
    else: exit()
```

In production, we might run our program like this -

```py
creds = {"ripley": "password1"}
app = ui(creds, input, print) # <-- args: creds, input, output
app.login()
```

In testing, we could write `test_ui_login_failure` like this -

```py
def test_ui_login_failure():
  def I (prompt): # input
    if prompt == "user:":
      return "foo"
    elif prompt == "pass:":
      return "bar"

  def O (s): # output
    assert s == "invalid login"

  app = ui({}, I, O)      # <-- args: empty creds, input, and output 
  app.login(lambda: None) # <-- args: exit handler
```

Writing `test_ui_login_success` might look like this -

```py
def test_ui_login_success():
  def I (prompt):
    if prompt == "user:":
      return "foo"
    elif prompt == "pass:":
      return "bar"

  def O (s):
    assert s == "foo logged in"

  app = ui({"foo": "bar"}, I, O)
  app.login(lambda: None)
```

---

**higher-order control**

Adding the `exit` parameter to `ui.login` gives us the control we need in the testing environment and it let's us implement a more sophisticated login routine, if needed -

```
def retry (n = 0, f = lambda _: None):
  if n <= 1:
    return lambda: None
  else:
    return lambda: f(retry(n - 1, f))

class ui:
  def __init__(self, creds, I, O):
    # ...

  def login(self, exit = None):
    # ...
    if (login(self.creds, u, p)):
      # ...
    elif exit is None:
      self.O("invalid login")
      self.login(retry(2, self.login)) # <-- retry login twice more
    else:
      self.O("invalid login")
      exit()
```

We can run `ui.login` same as last time -

```py
creds = {"ripley": "password1"}
app = ui(creds, input, print)
app.login()
```

The loop stops after 3 failed attempts -

```
user:foo
pass:bar
invalid login
user:spaghet
pass:meatbal
invalid login
user:ada  
pass:lovelace
invalid login
```

Our previous tests `test_ui_login_failure` and `test_ui_login_success` still pass. Of course you could write a test to verify the `retry` behaviour as well. This exercise is left for the reader.

---

**remarks**

Hopefully these techniques help show that subtle differences in how we write a program can results in dramatic differences in how we test it.